# What is an idiomatic Rust way to format a value to multiple kinds of strings?

Tags: rust

I have latitude in degrees in the form of a `f64` and I need to convert it into a `String`. At first I thought about implementing [`Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Display.html), like this:

```
struct Latitude(f64);

impl fmt::Display for Latitude {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{} {}", if self.0 > 0. { "N" } else { "S" }, self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lat: f64 = 45.;
    println!("{}", Latitude(lat));
}
```

After that, I have additional requirements. I need convert to one of two representations:

1. `N 70.152351`
2. `N 70° 09' 08"`

There is also an additional flag; when it is `false`, I need something like:

1. `- --.------`
2. `- --° -' -"`

The most simple way to implement this will be:

```
fn format_lat(degree: f64, use_min_sec_variant: bool, is_valid: bool) -> String;
```

However, I don't see any free functions in the Rust standard library.

Maybe I should use `struct Latitude(f64)` and implement a `to_string` method? Or maybe I should implement some other trait?

Comment: There are certainly [free functions in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/#functions); you must not have looked very far.

Comment: @Shepmaster Maybe he wanted `libc::free()` :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create wrapper types with different types of formatting and return them as a method:

```
struct Latitude(f64);
struct MinutesSeconds(f64);

impl Latitude {
    fn minutes_seconds(&self) -> MinutesSeconds {
        MinutesSeconds(self.0)
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for MinutesSeconds {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "latitude in a different format")
    }
}
```

This is the same idea as [`Path::display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display).

As for the valid / invalid concept, it sounds like you really want a `struct Latitude(Option<f64>)` and then provide `None` when it is invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Basically you're free to do what you want. Without more context on your goals, any method seems good enough for me.

Personally I'd do it as:

```
struct Latitude(f64);

impl Latitutde {
    pub fn format_as_x(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result<(), Error> {}

    pub fn format_as_y(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result<(), Error> {}
}
```

plus a `Display` trait + `to_format_x() -> String` convenience functions.

`format_as_y` are IMO best method since they handle errors, can take any formatter and don't need to allocate a `String` to return.

By the way, taking `bool` arguments is usually an anti-pattern: boolean trap.

Answer (score 2):

You can `impl Latitude` if you need to pass arguments or `impl ToString for Latitude` if you don't:

```
use std::string::ToString;

struct Latitude(f64);

// If you need parameterisation on your conversion function
impl Latitude {
    // You'd probably use a better-suited name
    pub fn to_string_parameterised(&self, use_min_sec_variant: bool) -> String {
        // Conversion code
        format!("{} {}", self.0, use_min_sec_variant)
    }
}

// If you don't need parameterisation and want to play nicely with 100% of all code elsewhere
impl ToString for Latitude {
    fn to_string(&self) -> String {
        // Conversion code
        format!("{}", self.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let lat = Latitude(45.0);
    println!("{}", lat.to_string_parameterised(false));
    println!("{}", lat.to_string());
}
```